VsCode's cmake plugin display "[ctest] Folder is not found in Test Explorer"
On vscode(v1.85.1), I installed the extensions CMake(v0.0.17) and CMake Tools(v17.7). I use Windows system, and use vscode to open cmake projects of WSL and remote Linux.
When using vscode to configure these cmake projects, I sometimes get an error "[ctest] Folder is not found in Test Explorer: /my/cmake/project/dir/" and then cmake won't configure. However, I can successfully configure it by using the cmake command directly in the terminal
I don't know what this error message means, nor do I know which specific folder this message is looking for. Sometimes, I delete the build folder, then delete the .vscode folder, and restart vscode, and the problem disappears. But sometimes this method doesn't work. Sometimes, specifying the ctest path in vscode's setting can also solve the problem.
I checked CMakeLists.txt and other cmake files, and there is no test related code (i.e. enable_testing() or add_test()). I also checked vscode's setting and there is no option to turn off ctest.
The general file structure of the cmake project is
MyCMakeProject
├── version.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Library1
    │   │   │── xxx.cpp
    │   │   └── xxx.h
    └── Library2
            │── xxx.cpp
            └── xxx.h

